# Continuing to be Able to Input with Scanner

Tags: java

Why is it that, in the code below, you are able to continuously enter numbers into the scanner? I feel the code would cause an infinite loop upon entering a double because

> userInput.hasNextDouble()

would always be true, since the value of userInput doesn't change throughout the loop.

I would like an explanation as to why the while condition does not cause an infinite loop.

```
 public class Testing
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Enter numbers: ");
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            int currentSize = 0;
            while (userInput.hasNextDouble()) 

            {

                    double nextScore = userInput.nextDouble();

                    currentSize++;


            }
            System.out.println(currentSize); 
            }




        }
```

Comment: you "feel", what about testing it? (Hint: type `1`, then `2`, then `3`, then `.`)

Comment: It's a figure of speech; looking at the code, the way I interpret it would cause it to have an infinite loop. On the other hand, what actually happens is that the user is able to continually input.

Answer (score 1):

The scanner class basically *scans* over tokens entered into the input stream.  When you call a `hasNextDouble()` or any `hasNext` method it will attempt to look at the next token in the stream.  It will wait until a token exists before returning the value, then calling `nextDouble()` will take that token and clear it from the stream so when you get back to `hasNextDouble()` it is going to wait until you enter another `token` into the stream.

Comment: Awesome, this is the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks for your help, and for everybody else's as well.

Answer (score 0):

`hasNextDouble()` is a method to indicate whether or not a double has been entered. If, in that code, the user enters something other than a double, for instance a `char` or `boolean`, the code will break out of the loop and print `currentSize`. A better thing to do would be like this:

```
        System.out.println("Enter numbers: ");
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int currentSize = 0;
        char choice = 'c';
        while (choice != 't') 

        {

                double nextScore = userInput.nextDouble();

                currentSize++;
                System.out.println("Enter \"c\" to enter more numbers, or \"t\" to exit.");
                choice = userInput.nextChar();
        }
        System.out.println(currentSize); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc of [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

> The next() and hasNext() methods and their primitive-type companion methods (such as nextInt() and hasNextInt()) first skip any input that matches the delimiter pattern, and then attempt to return the next token. Both hasNext and next methods may block waiting for further input. Whether a hasNext method blocks has no connection to whether or not its associated next method will block.

So if you don't enter a double, you immediately come out of that while loop.